# Is anyone in Madrid up for a get-together?

Tags: discusión, get-together

I'm staying near Madrid, Spain, for a week or two.

If anyone is in the area and interested in grabbing a coffee or beer, let me know! :)

---

Estoy cerca de Madrid, España para una o dos semanas.

Si le interesa a alguien reunirnos para un café o cerveza, avísame :)